# Insert into two tables at the same time insert new record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two SQL Server tables to work with in my database.

Here is my table `VMA_VehicleDetails_TB`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VMA_VehicleDetails_TB] 
(
    [VehRegID]   INT            IDENTITY (1000, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TraPNumber] NVARCHAR (60)  NOT NULL,
    [VehOwner]   NVARCHAR (60)  NOT NULL,
    [RegExpDate] DATE           NOT NULL,
    [InsExpDate] DATE           NOT NULL,
    [VehModel]   NVARCHAR (120) NOT NULL,
    [VehOrigin]  NVARCHAR (120) NOT NULL,
    [VehType]    NVARCHAR (80)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([VehRegID] ASC)
);
```

Here is my table `VMA_VehDrvAssigned_TB`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VMA_VehDrvAssigned_TB] 
(
    [VehRegID]   INT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [DrvRegID]   INT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [IsAssigned] BIT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_VMA_VehDrvAssigned_TB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([VehRegID] ASC)
);
```

I have use this stored procedure to add new registered vehicle id to the `VMA_VehDrvAssigned_TB`table. It is working fine.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addNewVehicleDetail_SP]
    @TraPNumber     NVARCHAR (60)
    ,@VehOwner      NVARCHAR (60)
    ,@RegExpDate    DATE
    ,@InsExpDate    DATE
    ,@VehModel      NVARCHAR (120)
    ,@VehOrigin     NVARCHAR (120)
    ,@VehType       NVARCHAR (80)
    ,@IsAssigned    BIT
    ,@DrvRegID      VARCHAR(60)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO [VMA_VehicleDetails_TB] (TraPNumber, VehOwner, RegExpDate, InsExpDate, VehModel, VehOrigin, VehType) 
    VALUES (@TraPNumber, @VehOwner, @RegExpDate, @InsExpDate, @VehModel, @VehOrigin, @VehType)

    INSERT INTO VMA_VehDrvAssigned_TB (VehRegID)
        SELECT 
            VehRegID = scope_identity();
END
```

Now, I want to add `@IsAssigned` and `@DrvRegID` to the same table while insert new record. But, I only know to add single column to the table. Did I something wrong??

Comment: This stored procedure does 1 insert and 1 only. You will need to call this multiple times to do x amount of inserts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify last INSERT.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addNewVehicleDetail_SP]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TraPNumber     NVARCHAR (60)
    ,@VehOwner      NVARCHAR (60)
    ,@RegExpDate    DATE
    ,@InsExpDate    DATE
    ,@VehModel      NVARCHAR (120)
    ,@VehOrigin     NVARCHAR (120)
    ,@VehType       NVARCHAR (80)
    ,@IsAssigned    BIT
    ,@DrvRegID      VARCHAR(60)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO [VMA_VehicleDetails_TB] (TraPNumber,VehOwner,RegExpDate,InsExpDate,VehModel,VehOrigin,VehType) 
    VALUES (@TraPNumber,@VehOwner,@RegExpDate,@InsExpDate,@VehModel,@VehOrigin,@VehType)
    INSERT INTO VMA_VehDrvAssigned_TB (VehRegID, DrvRegID, IsAssigned )
    SELECT scope_identity(), @DrvRegID, @IsAssigned ;
END
```

Comment: Thanks mate. So, I can do the same as for the `UPDATE Query` right?

Comment: @yeshansachithak exactly. I'm glad it helps